# kde-runtime on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, kde, kde-apps

I am trying to get the Dark Theme going in `Kdenlive` on Ubuntu 20.04 and apparently, you need to install `kde-runtime` package however, there is no such package available:

```
% sudo apt install kde-runtime
```

result:

```
% E: Package 'kde-runtime' has no installation candidate
```

Anyone know if there is a ppa out there for is package or another way to get this `Kdenlive` theme functionality working?

Answer (score 0):

In 2024, the available packages in Ubuntu based systems are:

1. `kde-full` - The KDE Plasma Full installation includes the KDE Plasma Desktop and an extensive set of applications, providing the most comprehensive KDE experience. To install this option, run the following command in your terminal.
2. `kde-standard` - This command downloads and installs the KDE Plasma Desktop along with a standard set of applications, providing a balanced KDE experience with essential tools and utilities.
3. `kde-plasma-desktop` - This command installs the KDE Plasma Desktop and a minimal set of applications, keeping the system resource usage low while still providing basic KDE functionality

source: https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-kde-plasma-on-linux-mint/

For the lowest bloat but fully functional KDE experience (eg. If for your main desktop), I strongly recommend `kde-standard`. This package has a bunch of important items that kde-plasma-desktop does not include such as icons and widgets (eg. quicklaunch)

Comment: I have recently converted to Linux Mint with ZFS Root and the kde-standard works like a charm after going down the `where the heck is quicklaunch` rabbit hole.